Exponential regression with three terms.
I was told to solve this by Least squares regression:
$$p(t) = a_{0} \exp(-1.5t) + a_{1}\exp(-0.3t) + a_{2}\exp(-0.05t)$$
along with some data for $t$ and $p(t)$.
I'm not sure how to proceed in this case. I know how to proceed in cases like $P(t) = a_{0} \exp(a_{1}t)$. I can linearize it with $\ln()$. But in this case, I don't see it helping. Can anyone give me a hint about the correct approach or suggest a book on the subject? (The textbooks I have don't seem to get into this specific case, which leads me to believe it's simpler than I'm thinking perhaps?)

This is a LINEAR equation. In the context of Least Squares Regression "linear" means wrt the parameters $a_0$ , $a_1$ , $a_2$ . It doesn't mean linear wrt the variable $t$ insofar the functions doesn't include more adjustable parameter. Thus use usual simple linear regression method.

Your goal is to minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (p(t_i)-p_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_o\exp(-1.5t_i)+a_1\exp(-0.3t_i)+a_2\exp(-0.05t_i)-p_i)^2$$
where $(t_i, p_i)$ are given to you.
Let $\exp(-1.5t_i)=x_{i1}, \exp(-0.3t_i)=x_{i2}, \exp(-0.05t_i)=x_{i3}$.
Now, this should be a problem that is familiar to you.
Can you take it from here?

Thanks for the feedback

If you have some data, say  $(t_i, y_i)_{1 \leq i\leq n}$, the least squares approximation corresponds to the minimization of
$$
Q(a_0, a_1, a_2)= \sum_{i=1}^n (p(t_i) - y_i)^2.
$$
Elementary multivariable calculus leads to the conclusion that optimal coefficients $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ are the solution of the linear system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum e^{-3 t_i} & \sum e^{-1.8 t_i} & \sum e^{-1.55 t_i}\\
\sum e^{-1.8 t_i} & \sum e^{-0.6 t_i} & \sum e^{-0.35 t_i}\\
\sum e^{-1.55 t_i} & \sum e^{-0.35 t_i} & \sum e^{-0.1 t_i}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum y_i e^{-1.5t_i}\\ \sum y_e e^{-0.3 t_i}\\ \sum y_i e^{-0.05 t_i}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Below you can find an example for some manufactured data, for which the least squares approximation is given by $p(t) = 1.18786 e^{-1.5 t}-2.80575 e^{-0.3 t}+3.77621 e^{-0.05 t}$.

